# Ruby script to save records into Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, model, terminal

I am trying to run a ruby script that parses a text file with album name, artist name, year on each line.  It should then save a new record into a Rails model called Album.

(buildDB.rb)

```
fh = File.open('albums.txt')

while line = fh.gets
    if ( line =~ /^(.+)\~\s(.+) \(\'(\d\d)\)/ )
        a = Album.new
        a.name   = $1
        a.artist = $2
        a.year   = $3
        a.save
    end
end
```

I am running **ruby buildDB.rb** in terminal which produces the message

```
buildDb.rb:12:in '<main>': uninitialized constant Album (NameError)
```

This made me think that the script could not find the model.  So I tried loading the rails environment by using

```
require "C:/ruby192/www/Project02/config/environment.rb"
```

at the top of the ruby script.  The script will run without errors but nothing is committed to the sqlite database.  I can also run find on the already existing Albums, it just seems I can't create new ones.

I am a rails noob so, there probably is a better way to do this (seeds.rb or a rake task maybe).  Any help or a direction to look into would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a rake task:

```
task :create_albums => :environment do
  fh = File.open('albums.txt')

  while line = fh.gets
    if ( line =~ /^(.+)\~\s(.+) \(\'(\d\d)\)/ )
      a = Album.new
      a.name   = $1
      a.artist = $2
      a.year   = $3
      a.save!
    end
  end
  fh.close
end
```

I added a ! to the save method so that any errors will throw an exeception. Also, make sure you close your files.

Comment: Actually the addition of the bang provided me with part of the problem.  I had the model attribute year set on presence => true, but one of the returned years from the regex was empty.  This threw an error on the script

Comment: Awesome!  Got it working and learned a little about rake tasks.  Thanks drummondj!

Answer (score 0):

Rake task is the way ahead. I would use FasterCSV as it will handle some of the data import for you.

```
namespace :import do
  desc "Import from a csv file"
  task :album_csv, [:filename] => :environment do |task, args|

  lines = FasterCSV.read(args[:filename]) rescue nil
  if lines
    lines.slice!(0) # remove the CSV header if there is one
    puts "# Processing #{lines.count} records"
    lines.each do |line|
      a = Album.new
      a.name   = line[0]
      a.artist = line[1]
      a.year   = line[2]
      a.save!
    end
  end
end
```

You can then call your rake task as:

```
rake import:album_csv[filename]
```